# Optimize postgresql query that executes faster in pgAdmin versus in an application along with concurrent queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

The following **SQL query** computes the sales by day for the schema listed below. After I ran VACUUM and ANALYZE on the Sales table, there were no updates to the data:

```
 SELECT 
          COUNT("Sales"."ID") AS "Sales->ID"
         ,"Sales"."StoreKeeper" AS "Sales->StoreKeeper"
FROM 
          "Sales" "Sales"
WHERE 
        (
          (
              "Sales"."DayOfSale"  >= 'Sun Aug 03 00:00:00 UTC 2014'
          )
        )
GROUP BY 
          "Sales"."StoreKeeper"
ORDER BY 
          "Sales->ID"
         ,"Sales->StoreKeeper"
```

**Sales Table Schema and indices:**

```
CREATE TABLE "Sales"
(
  "ID" text NOT NULL,
  "DayOfSale" timestamp without time zone,
  "StoreKeeper" text,
  "CustomerId" text, --ignorable, since no references or joins to any other table
  "Rating" text,
  "Location" text,
  "PaymentType" text, 
  "CashierId" text
 )


 CREATE INDEX saleid_index
   ON "Sales"
   USING btree
  ("ID" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" text_pattern_ops);


  CREATE INDEX sale_dayofsale_index
    ON "Sales"
    USING btree
    ("DayOfSale");
```

- **Table metadata**: 6500000 rows, all of which have the same value for "DayOfSale"
- **PostgreSQL version**: 9.3.4 on 64-bit CentOS
- **Hardware**: The dedicated machine has 8 GB RAM and only runs the PostGreSQL server
- **Buffer Sizes** in **postgresql.conf**:
  work_mem: 500 MB, shared_buffers= 2048MB, effective_cache_size=6138MB

**2 EXPLAIN outputs:**

1. The first for when the query is executing in PgAdmin by itself http://explain.depesz.com/s/m5b
2. http://explain.depesz.com/s/LIIG as part of an application where around 7 queries are fired on the table "Sales" at the same time

**Observations:**

1. The same plan is used whether the query is run within the app or in pgAdmin. 
   a. The sequential scan for all queries takes much longer in case of the app
   b. The no. of hits in the PostGreSQL buffer is more in case of the app as compared to PgAdmin

**Queries:**

1. The sequential scan takes the most time - Can it be optimized with
       tweaking some postgresql.conf setting?
2. Since depesz highlights the sequential scan as the area that takes the most time, is this the most likely spot to tweak to help performance improvement, right?

Comment: In the explain plan, I see `Filter: ("DayOfSale" >= '2014-08-03'::date)`. Is PostgreSQL performing that cast, or are we looking at different queries?

Comment: The query plan shows that the query needs nearly all rows from the Sales table, so the seqscan is a good choice. BTW: why do you use a text field as the PK for a table?

Comment: @Mike Sherill, PostgreSQL is performing the cast. There's only 1 query being discussed here

Comment: @joop, It would require a schema update, but do you think this will aid in improving the performance?

Comment: Try a compound index on `("DayOfSale", "StoreKeeper", "ID")`

Comment: I don't see the cast in 9.3.5 running on Ubuntu.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, There is no change to the EXPLAIN plan after adding the composite index that uses all the fields from the query

Answer (score 0):

I used your DDL to create the table and indexes, then populated the table with 2 million rows of meaningless data.

```
insert into "Sales" ("ID", "DayOfSale", "StoreKeeper", "CustomerId") 
select n, timestamp '2014-08-05 08:00' - (n || ' minutes')::interval, random_integer(1, 100), 3
from generate_series(1, 2000000) n;
analyze "Sales";
```

I chose the values for "DayOfSale" to guarantee that only a small subset of the table would satisfy the WHERE clause. I'd expect an index scan for this kind of data, and that's just what happened.

```
"Sort  (cost=173.76..173.76 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=2.639..2.647 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (count("ID")), "StoreKeeper""
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=173.74..173.75 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=2.542..2.557 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using sale_dayofsale_index on "Sales"  (cost=0.43..156.12 rows=3525 width=9) (actual time=0.023..1.184 rows=3360 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ("DayOfSale" >= '2014-08-03 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"Total runtime: 2.689 ms"
```

Also, the optimizer didn't do a cast from timestamp to date.

In my experience, if this table is really about sales, it would be rare to report on arbitrary time ranges. I'd expect queries on data like this to involve calendar weeks, calendar months, or calendar years. So you might benefit from

- a partial index,
- an index on an expression, or
- partitioning.

I'd also try a [covering index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index). PostgreSQL 9.2+ can do index-only scans; if you have a covering index, it doesn't need to read data from the table.

This query will show row counts for each month.

```
select date_trunc('month', "DayOfSale"), count(*)
from "Sales"
group by date_trunc('month', "DayOfSale")
order by 1;
```

In my case, it shows that the values range from Oct 2010 to Aug 2014. Only about 6000 rows are in Aug 2014, and not all those would satisfy your WHERE clause. It might be useful to paste the results of this query into your question.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Your answer prompted me to double-check the difference between yours and my setup and consequently edit the data set size and metadata in my question. In my table, there is a single value for "DayOfSale" - Is that why an Index scan is not being used?

Comment: @TreyJonn If a certain value represents more than a few percent of that column values then an index on it is not useful. Check [`cardinality`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29)

Comment: @TreyJonn: Yes, a single value in an index will usually give you a sequential scan. You might still benefit from a covering index, though. (One index covering the three columns in your query: DayOfSale, Storekeeper, ID)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it harder than it needs to be.  First, doing a COUNT(*) will just consider a record regardless of column such that you had of count(Sales.ID).  This is forcing the engine to back to the page data.  If all you care about is that a given StoreKeeper had X number of sales, count(*) is fine.

Next, the indexing.  I would have an index on (DayOfSale, StoreKeeper), this way, the WHERE clause can take advantage of the DayofSale part of the index, and StoreKeeper can be used for optimizing the group by.  I would completely remove the order by the sales ID number as all you care about is the count from a generic sense anyway.

Simplified should be

```
select
      s.StoreKeeper,
      count(*) as NumberOfSales
   from
      Sales s
   where
      s.DayOfSale >= 'Sun Aug 03 00:00:00 UTC 2014'

   group by
      s.StoreKeeper
   order by
      s.StoreKeeper
```